# Reading file content to Mysql stored procedure

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

i have a scenario where i have a file of the form,

```
id,class,type
1,234,gg
2,235,kk
3,236,hth
4,237,rgg
5,238,rgr
```

I also have a table in my database of the form `PROPS`,

```
id,class,property
1,7735,abc
2,3454,efg
3,235,hij
4,238,klm
5,24343,xyx
```

Now the first file and the db table are joined based on `class` so that final output will be of the form:

```
id,class,type,property
1,235,kk,hij
2,238,rgr,klm
```

Now, i can search the db table for each `class` record of the first file and so forth.

But this will take too much time.

Is there any way to do this same thing through a **MySQL STORED PROCEDURE**?

My question is whether there is a way to read the first file content line by line(WITHOUT MAKING USE OF A TEMPORARY TABLE), check the `class` with the `class` in the db table and insert the result into an output file and return the output file using MYSQL STORED PROCEDURE?

Comment: making use off a TEMPORARY TABLE where you store the file input within the stored prodedure would make it much eaiser  to generate the output file because you can simply write a `SELECT .... INTO FILE` kind off statement... p.s you can't return the output file with MySQL you can only return it's content..

Comment: Thank you for your input, but is there no alternate way to load the data without using any temporary table? Also, returning the content will be more than enough.

Comment: "no alternate way to load the data without using any temporary table".. Yes but that solution would be much harder.

Comment: We have limited space with large data. So for the time being we have to go with the "much harder solution". I would be very much grateful if you could suggest the solution.

Comment: By limited space you mean limited diskspace?

Comment: Indeed. Even creating a small temporary file would be counter productive.

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE (... ) ENGINE = MEMORY`  problem solved. this statement would only create a very small .frm (table definition) file on disk.... "Even creating a small temporary file would be counter productive"  time to enlarge your diskspace then.... Running a server with to little diskspace is counter productive..

Comment: " time to enlarge your diskspace then." Well if it was up to me, i'd have done it already. Nonetheless, could you showcase a rough sketch of how the procedure would look like then and put it up as an answer?. I'm terribly new to mysql stored procedures so just bear with me here.